# ToolStripLabel - DisplayStyle is Image : Selection

Tags: c#, winforms

There's a `ToolStrip` in my form and inside that there's 1 `ToolStripButton` & 
2 `ToolStripLabels`.

One of the `ToolStripLabel` has `DisplayStyle` set to `Image`.

Now when the focus is inside the ToolStrip, i can navigate between
the ToolStripButton & one ToolStripLabel with left/right arrow keys.

But the problem is, I can't navigate to ToolStripLabel with DisplayStyle set
to Image.

There's no indication of that ToolStripLabel being selected via left/right arrow keys.

**Is there a way I can select a ToolStripLabel with DisplayStyle set to Image?**

Comment: Probably you solved the problem yourself. I think the post answers your question and it would be great if you kindly vote and accept the answer :) It's not compulsory at all, but it's reasonable, recommended and your kindness. It makes the question and answer more useful for future readers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I recommend using a `ToolStripButton` if you want to make the item interactive, but about your question:

> Is there a way I can select a ToolStripLabel with DisplayStyle set to
>   Image?

Yes there is.

- To be able to move between items, first set `TabStop` property of `ToolStrip` to `true`.
- Then for each `ToolStripLabel` that you want to be able to move to using arrow keys, set [`IsLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel.islink(v=vs.110).aspx) property of to `true`.

To test, you can handle `Click` event of the item, and when you move item using arrow keys, then press enter to raise click event and for example show a message box.